# How does one find a UIView... when there's no self.view?

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel, hierarchy

So I've been fighting this one for a while as novice with iOS - I'm sure it's either a basic concept I'm missing, or a property I haven't run across yet that I need to reference.

Scenario:  View controller creates a UIScrollView.  UIView is created as a container for several UILabels (describing an event, venue and time).  Method is called repeatedly to create these UILabels within the block.  Creating these labels one by one works fine - simply adding each to the view - but when I move the code to a method and reuse it, abstracting such things as text size, indent, etc, I can't refer to the same parent view (because it's not a View Controller?), or search using viewWithTag (returns nothing) to find the parent.

Is this a simple fix, or is my basic structure flawed?  Many thanks in advance for your time!

Header:

```
//
//  ScheduleColumn.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ScheduleColumn : UIView {

}

- (void)makeTextBlock:(int)parentViewID label:(NSString*)label textSize:(int)textSize indent:(int)indent y:(int)y width:(int)width height:(int)height;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
//
//  ScheduleColumn.m
//

#import "ScheduleColumn.h"

@implementation ScheduleColumn

// makeTextBlock: type, text, textSize, indent, build_y, width, height

// type: 0 = Title, 1 = Subtitle, 2 = Times
// text: Line content
// textSize: self-explanatory
// indent: indent from left side of parent
// build_y: # of units down from top of parent view to build
// width & height: self-explanatory

- (void)makeTextBlock:(int)parentViewID label:(NSString*)label textSize:(int)textSize indent:(int)indent y:(int)y width:(int)width height:(int)height {

    double unixTime;

unixTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

NSLog(@"makeTextBlock called");
NSLog(@"parentViewID: %u", parentViewID);
NSLog(@"label: %@", label);
NSLog(@"textSize: %u", textSize);
NSLog(@"indent: %u", indent);
NSLog(@"y: %u", y);
NSLog(@"width: %u", width);
NSLog(@"height: %u", height);
NSLog(@"time: %u", unixTime);

UILabel *textView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(indent, y, width, height)];   
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textView.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
textView.numberOfLines = 0;
textView.tag = unixTime;

textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PetitaMedium" size: textSize];
textView.text = label;

CGSize constraintTextSize;
constraintTextSize.width = width;
constraintTextSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
CGSize theTextSize = [label sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PetitaMedium" size: textSize] constrainedToSize:constraintTextSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CGRect newTextFrame = textView.frame;
newTextFrame.size.height = theTextSize.height;
textView.frame = newTextFrame;

UIView *parentView = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:parentViewID];

[parentView addSubview:textView];
[textView release];

NSLog(@"--- break ---");

}
```

.. and finally, the calls from the View Controller:

```
int build_y;
int subtitle_indent;

build_y = 30;
subtitle_indent = 20;

UIView *blockView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 0, build_y, 185, 50)];
blockView.tag = 100;
[FireworksContent addSubview:blockView];

// Add top line
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, blockView.bounds.size.width, 0.5)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[blockView addSubview:lineView];

// Add Block Text
ScheduleColumn *blockText = [ScheduleColumn alloc];
[blockText makeTextBlock:blockView.tag label:@"Venue" textSize:18 indent:subtitle_indent y:build_y width:blockView.bounds.size.width height:20];
[blockText makeTextBlock:blockView.tag label:@"ShowTitle" textSize:12 indent:subtitle_indent y:build_y width:blockView.bounds.size.width height:20];
[blockText makeTextBlock:blockView.tag label:@"Showtime" textSize:36 indent:subtitle_indent y:build_y width:blockView.bounds.size.width height:20];


[lineView release];
[blockText release];

[blockView release];
```

... the viewWithTag line fails because "self" doesn't have a view... changing the class to a UIViewController lets it run, but still no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class method that returns a new view rather than an instance method that returns void would make more sense.

```
+(UIView *)makeTextBlock:(int)parentViewID label:(NSString*)label textSize:(int)textSize indent:(int)indent y:(int)y width:(int)width height:(int)height
```

Create the view as you want, and return that view at the end of the method.

Then you can create several of these views and hold a reference to them in your view controller if you want.

```
UIView *blockText1 = [ScheduleColumn makeTextBlock .....];
[self.view addSubview: blockText1];
```

Comment: ....aaaand that's why I love the Internet.  You, sir, are a gentleman.  I need to think in objects, not scripts!  BTW, need a colon after that "addSubview". :)  Thanks very much for your time!